# Assign a JSON parsed string to a button's onClick

Tags: android, json, string, url, onclick

I have an application which acts as a blog and gets its articles from the net with JSON API. The API gives me the URLs to the articles too but how can I put them as onClick to the individual buttons? 
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Use a `RecyclerView` where each item represents button with an article.

Comment: I'm using `ListView` to fill cardviews and have the button in the cardview as well . Can I do it somehow with `ListView`?

Comment: Yep. Are you using some kind of adapter? Just store your list of article urls in a field and then in your `getView()` method, get your article by adapter position.